# Login que compara a entrada do usuário com os dados criptografados no MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, criptografia

Estou com dificuldade em achar uma forma de comparar os dados inseridos pelo usuário em um `jPasswordField` na tela de Login e comparar com a senha criptografada em AES e salva no banco de dados MySQL. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Código do botão Salvar que registra o usuário e a senha codificada no BD:

```
private void jButtonSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    if (jTextFieldUsername.getText().trim().equals("") || jPasswordFieldPassword.getPassword().equals("") || jPasswordFieldConfirmPassword.getPassword().equals("")){
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please, inform a username and password.");

        } else {

            if(Arrays.equals(jPasswordFieldPassword.getPassword(), jPasswordFieldConfirmPassword.getPassword())){
                String password = new String(jPasswordFieldPassword.getPassword());
                System.out.println(password);
                try {
                    KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
                    SecretKey sk = kg.generateKey();
                    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sk);
                    byte [] encrypt = cipher.doFinal(password.getBytes());
                    System.out.println(encrypt);

                    String admin = "";
                    if(jRadioButtonAdministrator.isSelected()){
                        admin="Yes";
                    }else{
                        admin="No";
                    }
                    String vendor = "";
                    if(jRadioButtonVendor.isSelected()){
                        vendor="Yes";
                    }else{
                        vendor="No";
                    }
                    Connection con = ConexaoMySQL.getInstance().getConnection();

                    String cmd = "insert into users (username, password, administrator, vendor, idEmployee, status) VALUES "
                            + "('"+jTextFieldUsername.getText()+"', '"+encrypt+"', '"+admin+"', '"+vendor+"', '"+jTableEmployeeInfo.getValueAt(jTableEmployeeInfo.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString()+"', 'Active')";

                    con.createStatement().executeUpdate(cmd);

                    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username successfully registered.", "Success", 1);

                    dispose();

                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection/data error. Please, inform a username and a password", "Attention!", 2);
                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(RegisterNewUserJDialogForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
            } else {
                    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fields password and confirm password do not match");
            }
        }
}
```

Código do botão de login tela LoginJDialogForm:

```
private void jButtonLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    UserDAO dao = new UserDAO();
    if(dao.verifyLogin(jTextFieldUser.getText(), new String (jPasswordFieldPassword.getPassword()))){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome!");
        MainScreenForm main = new MainScreenForm();
        main.setVisible(true);
        dispose();
    }else{
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username and/or password.");
    }
}
```

UserDAO:

```
public class UserDAO {

    public boolean verifyLogin(String username, String password){
        Connection con = ConexaoMySQL.getInstance().getConnection();
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        boolean verify = false;

        try {
            stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? and password = ?");
            stmt.setString(1, username);
            stmt.setString(2, password);
            System.out.println(stmt);

            rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()){
                verify=true;
            }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username and/or password");
            Logger.getLogger(UserDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return verify;
    }
}
```

Comment: Uma coisa que percebi: cadastrei a senha '123456' para um usuário e ela foi salva no BD como '[B@4b00b75d'. Quando tento logar com o mesmo usuário e passando a senha '123456', através do mesmo processo de encrypt, o System.out.println(encrypt) captura a senha como '[B@20feb86d'. Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que notei, você está usando no Select o valor do password digitado no formulário de login. Para testar com o banco de dados, precisa testar o password criptografado. Então, você precisa criptografar o password recuperado do formulário e então usar essa valor criptografado no select. Algo do tipo:

```
public boolean verifyLogin(String username, String password){
    Connection con = ConexaoMySQL.getInstance().getConnection();
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    boolean verify = false;

    String encrypt = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(password);

    /*KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecretKey sk = kg.generateKey();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sk);
    byte [] encrypt = cipher.doFinal(password.getBytes());*/

    try {
        stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? and password = ?");
        stmt.setString(1, username);
        stmt.setString(2, encrypt);
        System.out.println(stmt);

        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){
            verify=true;
        }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username and/or password");
        Logger.getLogger(UserDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return verify;
}
```

O ideal seria criar um método com a ação de criptografia, dai seria só chamar o método toda vez que precisar criptografar a senha. Fica mais simples, reaproveita a lógica.

Comment: tentei, mas primeiro deu um erro que não consegue converter byte[] para String. Converti o encrypt para String com `String password2 = encrypt.toString();` e passei `stmt.setString(2, password2);`, mas mesmo assim não consegui fazer a comparação parece que '123456' quando criptografada e salva no banco de dados, fica com valor diferente de '123456' quando passada pelo usuário na tela de login e criptografada para comparação. Será que pode ser o `jPasswordField`? Obrigado.

Comment: Eu aconselho você a usar a biblioteca  [Apache Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/index.html) para realizar a criptografia. É bem mais simples. Vou editar minha resposta anterior adicionando o código usando essa biblioteca,vai ver como é simples.

Comment: A propósito, será necessário salvar a senha usando também essa alteração.

Comment: funcionou! Adicionei o `Base64` para converter. Muito obrigado! :) Pra quem estiver com a mesma dúvida, vou colocar o código modificado em uma resposta nova logo abaixo.

Answer (score 0):

Segue código modificado e funcionando.

Botão de registrar o usuário:

```
private void jButtonSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    if (jTextFieldUsername.getText().trim().equals("") || jPasswordFieldPassword.getPassword().equals("") || jPasswordFieldConfirmPassword.getPassword().equals("")){
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please, inform a username and password.");

        } else {

            if(Arrays.equals(jPasswordFieldPassword.getPassword(), jPasswordFieldConfirmPassword.getPassword())){
                String password = new String(jPasswordFieldPassword.getPassword());
                System.out.println(password);
                try {
                    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
                    byte[] hash = digest.digest(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    String encodedPassword = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hash);

                    String admin = "";
                    if(jRadioButtonAdministrator.isSelected()){
                        admin="Yes";
                    }else{
                        admin="No";
                    }
                    String vendor = "";
                    if(jRadioButtonVendor.isSelected()){
                        vendor="Yes";
                    }else{
                        vendor="No";
                    }
                    Connection con = ConexaoMySQL.getInstance().getConnection();

                    String cmd = "insert into users (username, password, administrator, vendor, idEmployee, status) VALUES "
                            + "('"+jTextFieldUsername.getText()+"', '"+encodedPassword+"', '"+admin+"', '"+vendor+"', '"+jTableEmployeeInfo.getValueAt(jTableEmployeeInfo.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString()+"', 'Active')";

                    con.createStatement().executeUpdate(cmd);
                    System.out.println(cmd);
                    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username successfully registered.", "Success", 1);

                    dispose();

                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection/data error. Please, inform a username and a password", "Attention!", 2);

                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(RegisterNewUserJDialogForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            } else {
                    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fields password and confirm password do not match");
            }
        }
}
```

Botão de login:

```
private void jButtonLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    UserDAO dao = new UserDAO();
    if(dao.verifyLogin(jTextFieldUser.getText(), new String (jPasswordFieldPassword.getPassword()))){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome!");
        MainScreenForm main = new MainScreenForm();
        main.setVisible(true);
        dispose();
    }else{
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username and/or password.");
        jTextFieldUser.setText("");
        jPasswordFieldPassword.setText("");
    }

}
```

UserDAO:

```
public class UserDAO {

    public boolean verifyLogin(String username, String password){
        Connection con = ConexaoMySQL.getInstance().getConnection();
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        boolean verify = false;
        System.out.println(password);

        try {
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            byte[] hash = digest.digest(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            String encodedPassword = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hash);

            stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? and password = ?");
            stmt.setString(1, username);
            stmt.setString(2, encodedPassword);
            System.out.println(stmt);

            rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()){
                String administratorDB = rs.getString("administrator");
                String statusDB = rs.getString("status");

                if("Yes".equals(administratorDB) && "Active".equals(statusDB)){
                verify=true;
                }else{
                    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The informed username does not have administrator permission.");

                }
            }

        } catch (SQLException | NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UserDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }

        return verify;
    }
}
```